# Best way to split a string output with predefined parts into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, types, type-conversion

Currently, I am dealing with an output from a program (cmus) that I want to convert into an array in Python, this is an example output from cmus that I am handling:

> status playing file /home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac artist Tsegue-maryam Guebrou albumartist Tsegue-maryam Guebrou album Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo) discnumber 1 tracknumber 14 title The Story of the Wind date 2005-12-01 duration 166

Every output will be that, following this order:

```
status
file
artist
albumartist
album
discnumber
tracknumber
title
date
duration
```

I have been learning a lot of python lately, and have been trying to crack this for the entire day, how would I form a dictionary that looks like this from that output:

```
csum_output = {
    "status": "playing",
    "file": "/home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac",
    "artist": "Tsegue-maryam Guebrou",
    "albumartist": "Tsegue-maryam Guebrou",
    "album": "Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo)",
    "discnumber": "1",
    "tracknumber": "14",
    "title": "The Story of the Wind",
    "date": "2005-12-01",
    "duration": "166"
}
```

I have tried a lot of things, all without much success. I did find this actually on the csum wiki:

```
def status_data(item):
   """Return the requested cmus status data."""
 
   # We loop through cmus status data and use each of its known data
   # types as 'delimiters', collecting data until we reach one,
   # inserting it into the dictionary -- rinse and repeat.
 
   # cmus helper script provides our data as argv[1].
   cmus_data = sys.argv[1]
 
   # Split the data into an easily-parsed list.
   cmus_data = cmus_data.split()
 
   # Our temporary collector list.
   collector = []
 
   # Dictionary that will contain our parsed-out data.
   cmus_info = {'status':"",
                'file':"",
                'artist':"",
                'album':"",
                'discnumber':"",
                'tracknumber':"",
                'title':"",
                'date':"",
                'duration':""}
 
   # Loop through cmus data and write it to our dictionary.
   last_found = "status"
   for value in cmus_data:
       collector.append(value)
       # Check to see if cmus value matches dictionary key.
       for key in cmus_info:
           # If a match has been found, record the data.
           if key == value:
               collector.pop()
               cmus_info[last_found] = " ".join(collector)
               collector = []
               last_found = key
 
   # Return whatever data main() requests.
   return cmus_info[item]
```

Sadly, after a lot of testing, this seems to not return the duration, which is needed for my program.

Comment: How about changing `cmus_info` inside `status_data` function on your desired keys?

Comment: You need to add `cmus_info[last_found] = ''.join(collector)` after the `for` loop has completed to add the final value to the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in @snakecharmerb's comment, you collect the data of the last key (duration), but you never add it to the dictionary.

You have to add a line after the loop:

```
for value in cmus_data:
    collector.append(value)
    ...

cmus_info[last_found] = " ".join(collector) # here, last_found is "duration"
```

But what happens if the key is in the artist name (or in the song title, album name, ...)? You'll get an error (note that I use an auxiliary function to extract the data from a string into a dictionary, for testing purpose):

```
def extract_data(cmus_data):
   cmus_data = cmus_data.split()
   collector = []

   # Dictionary that will contain our parsed-out data.
   cmus_info = {'status':"",
                'file':"",
                'artist':"",
                'album':"",
                'discnumber':"",
                'tracknumber':"",
                'title':"",
                'date':"",
                'duration':""}

   last_found = "status"
   for value in cmus_data:
       collector.append(value)
       for key in cmus_info:
           if key == value:
               collector.pop()
               cmus_info[last_found] = " ".join(collector)
               collector = []
               last_found = key

   cmus_info[last_found] = " ".join(collector)

   return cmus_info


print(extract_data("status playing file /home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac artist Tsegue-maryam Guebrou album Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo) discnumber 1 tracknumber 14 title The Story of the status date 2005-12-01 duration 166"))
```

Note: `title The Story of the`**`status`**. Ouptut:

```
{'status': '', 'file': '/home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac', 'artist': 'Tsegue-maryam Guebrou', 'album': 'Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo)', 'discnumber': '1', 'tracknumber': '14', 'title': 'The Story of the', 'date': '2005-12-01', 'duration': '166'}
```

The `status` in the title cleared the previous status.

Since you know the expected order of keys, you should take advantage of this information:

```
def extract_data2(cmus_data):
   cmus_data = cmus_data.split()
   collector = []

   # Dictionary that will contain our parsed-out data.
   cmus_keys = ['status', 'file', 'artist', 'album', 'discnumber', 'tracknumber', 'title', 'date', 'duration']
   cmus_info = {}

   last_found = None
   it = iter(cmus_keys)
   expected_key = next(it) # the first key
   for value in cmus_data:
        if value == expected_key:
            if last_found is not None: # not the first key
                cmus_info[last_found] = " ".join(collector)
                collector = []
            last_found = expected_key
            expected_key = next(it, None) # we know the next expected key
        else:
            collector.append(value)

   cmus_info[last_found] = " ".join(collector)

   return cmus_info


print(extract_data2("status playing file /home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac artist Tsegue-maryam Guebrou album Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo) discnumber 1 tracknumber 14 title The Story of the status date 2005-12-01 duration 166"))
```

Output

```
{'status': 'playing', 'file': '/home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac', 'artist': 'Tsegue-maryam Guebrou', 'album': 'Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo)', 'discnumber': '1', 'tracknumber': '14', 'title': 'The Story of the status', 'date': '2005-12-01', 'duration': '166'}
```

It works, but should also add a check of the data format, e.g. duration is an integer number, etc. before draining the collector.

The easiest solution would perhaps be a regex:

```
import re

REGEX = re.compile("^status (?P<status>.+?) file (?P<file>.+?) artist (?P<artist>.+?) album (?P<album>.+?) discnumber (?P<discnumber>\d+?) tracknumber (?P<tracknumber>\d+?) title (?P<title>.+?) date (?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) duration (?P<duration>\d+?)$")

def extract_data3(cmus_data):
    return REGEX.match(cmus_data).groupdict()

print(extract_data3("status playing file /home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac artist Tsegue-maryam Guebrou album Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo) discnumber 1 tracknumber 14 title The Story of the status date 2005-12-01 duration 166"))
```

Output:

```
{'status': 'playing', 'file': '/home/admin/Archive/Public/Music/Artists/Tsegue-maryam Guebrou/Ethiopiques vol. 21 Emahoy (Piano Solo) (Album)/14 The Story of the Wind.flac', 'artist': 'Tsegue-maryam Guebrou', 'album': 'Ethiopiques, vol. 21: Emahoy (Piano Solo)', 'discnumber': '1', 'tracknumber': '14', 'title': 'The Story of the status', 'date': '2005-12-01', 'duration': '166'}
```

Of course, this remains fragile because the format may have execptions (e.g. something like `date unknown` will make the function fail).

Answer (score 0):

Just another simpler approach would be

```
cmus_keys = ["status", "file", "artist", "albumartist", "album", "discnumber", "tracknumber", "title", "duration"]
for key in cmus_keys:
    cmus_data = cmus_data.replace(key + " ", key + "#").replace(" "+ key, "#" + key)
cmus_list = cmus_data.split("#")
cmus_info = dict(zip(cmus_list[::2], cmus_list[1::2]))
```

Here, cmus_info will contain the key value pair of data.